# :focus with Adjacent selector won't work on IE7

Tags: css

I am trying to show span which is right after the input element, when input has focus.
works on all browsers except IE7:

```
input:focus + span{ .. }  // won't work
input + span{ .. }        // does work
```

Anyone knows if this is a known bug?
I haven't found information about this on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet explorer 7 does not support :focus

the only solution i can think of is to use javascript `onfocus` and `onblur` to simulate this effect on IE

example:

```
element.onfocus = function () {
  this.className = "theFocusCssRuleClass";
}

element.ononblur = function () {
  this.className = "theNormalCssRuleClass";
}
```

Comment: @vsync: sorry i dont understand your comments

Answer (score 1):

Does not support `:focus` you could add this though :

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Upgrade MSIE5.5-7 to be compatible with MSIE8.

Comment: ha, dean adwards, I used to use this script years ago.

Comment: I can write JS myself, but I wanted a pure CSS solution to something, just for fun. I regard JS use for these type of things as abomination

Comment: (p,a,c,k,e,r) ? ie 7 does not support focus, so pur css is not going to happen unfortunately.